# Unable to connect to Windows 8 PC via network

Tags: windows, macos, networking

I installed an upgrade of a clean copy from Windows 7 to Windows 8. After this, I am unable to connect to the PC via network from both a Windows and OS X host.  I am able to see the PC on the network (or connect to server through smb) but it fails the authentication on the machine. When on a Mac it gives me the user dialog but fails all of my accounts (even administrator). When I select guest I can see the public folder and the other shared folders, but I when go into any folder other than Users I get disconnected immediately.

When connecting to the PC from another Windows machine, it automatically appears to assume to log into guest (guest account is turned on on the Windows 8 machine) and does the same as above where I can access the Users folder and nothing else.

This only appears to be an authentication issue as I am able to run sharemouse over the network to connect and see the Win8 and OS x with each other.

I have done a couple of other tips and can confirm the following:

- Network Discovery is on
- File and printer sharing is on (it indicates the Windows current network profile is Private, if that helps?)
- Allow Windows to manage homegroup connections is on.
- Guest or Public has network discovery on, file and printer sharing is on
- Public folder sharing is off
- Password protected sharing is off
- Usergroups has everyone in it.
- I have Kaspersky installed but even when turned off the same happens.

This is utterly frustrating so if anyone could assist with either some ideas or a way on how to reset my network and privacy settings back to "default" without reinstalling I would be ever so grateful.

Comment: I'm no expert, but have you tried under Control Panel -> Allow remote connections? (forget exactly which path to take, but I'm sure you'll find it). Even before I checked this box, all other network-based sharing was successful. I suspect, however, that this may only apply to RDP.

EDIT: After checking the box, it also allows you to set it up by user

Comment: Is Homegroup or Network Sharing turned on? That could possibly be a problem. Give it a try

Comment: @AK4749 - I tried your idea but unfortunately its not the solution

Comment: Hey @JustinD, I have tried homegroup both on and off (off currently) and network sharing is definately on. I have 3 folders shared and I ensured I gave everyone all permissins and I gave NETWORK all all permissions, thanks for the tips though guys

Comment: @MauritzSwanepoel ok, like I said, I think my comment only applied for RDP connections :( let's try to get some more info: what exactly do you mean by connect? Are you trying to browse the filesystem of the computer? Like network drive? Or are you trying to remote in via VNC/RDP? or doing something else that I'm not thinking of? If you can answer this I'm sure more knowledgeable people on this exchange can answer your question!

Comment: From what I can see it's really only file sharing and printer sharing which does not want to work properly. When logged in as guest, I see all of the shared folders but can only access Users. Over and above that I can ping and do any other noticable network activity between all of the PC's. It has to be something with the authentication part for file sharing, but I have gone through everyhing I know with no luck